# Como transformar o espaço de um input text para %20?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como transformar o espaço de um input text para %20?
Gostaria de altera texto em questão para ser transportado em uma url

Estou gerado uma url para que as informações do site seja incluída no inicio da conversa ("text=sua%20mensagem")
exemplo:
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=seunumerodetelefone&text=sua%20mensagem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se esta em em um `<input>` somente a mensagem basta usar [**`rawurlencode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php), assim no PHP:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = rawurlencode($_POST['message']);

    $url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=seunumerodetelefone&text=' . $message;

    var_dump($url); //Somente para testar a URL
}
```

Supondo que o form esteja assim

```
<form action="pagina.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="message">
<button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Se for JavaScript pode usar `encodeURIComponent`:

```js
var message = document.querySelector("#message"),
    testBtn = document.querySelector("#testar");

testBtn.onclick = function () {
    var url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=seunumerodetelefone&text=';
    var urlmessage = url + encodeURIComponent(message.value);
    
    console.log(urlmessage);
};
```

```html
Digite algo: <input type="text" id="message" value=""><br>
<button id="testar">Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o str_replace:

`str_replace(' ', '%20', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=seunumerodetelefone&text=sua mensagem')`